# Format time 24 hours to 12 hours with AM/PM and display inside popover fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to format the time from 24 hours to 12 hours with AM/PM and display it in popover.
This is my code:

```
        eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent) {
                var t1 = event.start;
                var t2 = event.end;

        $(this).popover({
            html:true,
            placement: 'left',
            trigger: 'hover',
            content: t1 + ' - ' + t2,
            container: '#calendar'
        }).popover('toggle');
        }
```

I search for the answers here but it doesnt work in popover. So i decided to ask for it.
This is the code i used. 
It works on here, but not in popover.

```
       eventRender: function(event, element) {
            var t1 = event.time;
            var t2 = event.time2;
            var tmpArr = t1.split(':'), time12;
                if(+tmpArr[0] == 12) {
                    time12 = tmpArr[0] + ':' + tmpArr[1] + 'P';
                } else {
                if(+tmpArr[0] == 00) {
                    time12 = '12:' + tmpArr[1] + 'A';
                } else {
                if(+tmpArr[0] > 12) {
                    time12 = (+tmpArr[0]-12) + ':' + tmpArr[1] + 'P';
                } else {
                    time12 = (+tmpArr[0]) + ':' + tmpArr[1] + 'A';
                }
                }
                }

            var tmpArrs = t2.split(':'), time13;
                if(+tmpArrs[0] == 12) {
                    time13 = tmpArrs[0] + ':' + tmpArrs[1] + 'P';
                } else {
                if(+tmpArrs[0] == 00) {
                    time13 = '12:' + tmpArrs[1] + 'A';
                } else {
                if(+tmpArrs[0] > 12) {
                    time13 = (+tmpArrs[0]-12) + ':' + tmpArrs[1] + 'P';
                } else {
                    time13 = (+tmpArrs[0]) + ':' + tmpArrs[1] + 'A';
                }
                }
                } 

                element.find('.fc-content').append(t1 + "-" + t2 +);
        }
```

Comment: This is insane. You don't need to do crazy string operations to write out the time. fullCalendar relies on momentJS, as you must know if you've been using it (you'd have had to include it when you set up your calendar), and momentJS does all kinds of clever time formatting. See the answer below and also the docs at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ for more general info about formatting dates and times.

Comment: thank you.@ADyson im just a beginner and i have limited knowledge about fullcalendar.

Comment: I get that but surely it occurred to you there might be a better way of printing a date? You are not the first person to want to display a date in another format. I suspect googling it would have brought you to the momentJS site eventually too - so if you're a beginner here's a tip: before creating a very complicated piece of code to do something very trivial (such as this), check whether someone's thought of a better way already. Chances are, in 2018, they probably have :-)

Comment: yeah, i do a lot of search. thats why i came out for this insane code. hehe i already found out that there so much easier way to do it . i just need to improve myself in searchin and studying. thanks @ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `moment.js` included in your webpage (as FullCalendar needs it in any case) use the following code in place of declaring `var t1` and `var t2`

```
var t1 = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format("h:mm A")
var t2 = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end ).format("h:mm A")
```

P.S. You don't need to work out the 12 hour format manually, `moment.js` does this for you

Comment: i tried it but still doesnt work. It says invalid date. Btw, the start and end value is just this format (00:00:00). Its doesnt have the date.

Comment: How are you adding events then? Can you show me an example? Every event requires a start value but an end value is not required in which case you can build up your popover string differently in those cases in order for it to not show invalid date.

Comment: I made a separate field which is just for time. there is still start date and end date. but im planning to add the time included in the date, not the separate way because im having difficulty. thanks anyway. your code works perfectly when the time is included in the start and end.

Comment: Cool, I hope it was of some assistance

Comment: can you answer my another question, here it is. About the resizing of events. Im unable to resize it if i add time for the start and end date. please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363002/fullcalendar-event-resizing-is-not-working-when-time-is-added-in-start-and-end-d