# fullCalendar event resizing is not working when time is added in start and end date

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

Whenever I put the time in start and end, the event won't resize. But when the time is in 00:00:00 I can now resize it.

[image]

Then it works when the time is 00:00:00.

[image]

My full code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'today add_event',
          center: 'prev title next',
          right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        eventOrder: 'start',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
          $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
          $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
          $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                            $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                            $('#ModalEdit #start').val(event.start.format('dddd, MMM DD-YYYY'));
                            $('#ModalEdit #end').val(event.end.format('dddd, MMM DD-YYYY'));
                    });
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
          edit(event);
        }
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {
          edit(event);
        },
        events: [
          <?php 
            foreach($events as $event): 
                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
            if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else{
                $start = $event['start'];
                                  }
            if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $end = $end[0];
            }else{
                $end = $event['end'];
            }
      ?>
            {
            id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
            title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
            start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
            end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
          },
        <?php endforeach;?>
        ],

    });
    function edit(event){
      start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      if(event.end){
        end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
      }
      else{
        end = start;
      }
      id =  event.id;
      Event = [];
      Event[0] = id;
      Event[1] = start;
      Event[2] = end;
      $.ajax({
        url: 'editEventDate.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          Event:Event}
        ,
        success: function(rep) {
          if(rep == 'OK'){
          }
          else{
            alert('Could not be saved. try again.');
          }
        }
      }
    );
    }
    }
    );
```

Please help me to figure out what is the problem. I could not add the time to the start and end date.

Comment: Does it work if you add `allDay: false` to your event? Keep in mind you can't resize allDay events and it should be resizeable in the "week" view.

Comment: thanks @GregoryNikitas, i will try that and update you asap if that will work.

Comment: @GregoryNikitas it didn't actually work. rather if i add the `allDay: true` in the `events:` , then i can now resize it but the time becomes 00:00:00.